# Regular Expression for replacing a-Tags in HTML where href-attribute starting with http://

Tags: html, regex, coldfusion, replace

I want to match all Links in my HTML-content-variable where the href starts with http://www.example.com

**Example**

should match:

`<a href="http://www.example.com">foo</a>`

shouldn't match:

`<a href="/bar/">bar</a>`

also match (with linebreaks and other HTML-tags inside anchor):

```
<a class="bla" id="blubb" href="http://www.example.com/asdf/" title="oops">
<img src="..." alt="" />
</a>
```

I started with something like this:

```
<CFSAVECONTENT variable="html">
    <a class="bla" id="blubb" href="http://www.example.com/asdf/" title="oops">
        <img src="..." alt="" /> some Text
    </a>
</CFSAVECONTENT>
<CFSET result = REReplace(html, "<a[^>]*href="http://www\.example\.com[^"]*"[^>]?>([^<]+)</a>", "\1") />
```

but of course this one wouldn't match my last link example with the img-tag inside a-tag...

Any hints on this one?

Comment: Upon further investigation, the question title doesn't match what you are asking: Do you want to match all links that start with http://, or all links that start with http://www.example.com ? I'll have to modify  my answer based on what you want.

Comment: It should match all Links starting with http://www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
<CFSAVECONTENT variable="html">
    <a class="bla" id="blubb" href="http://www.example.com/asdf/" title="oops">
        <img src="..." alt="" /> some Text
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/foo">foo</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">abc</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/bar">bar</a>
</CFSAVECONTENT>
```

Use:

```
<cfset links = ReMatch('<a[^>]*href="http://www\.example\.com[^"]*"[^>]*>(.+?)</a>', html) />
```

'links' is now an array of matched URLs (anchors 1, 2, and 4 should be in the array).

Bear in mind my answer was framed under the assumption you wanted to match all anchors that start with `http://www.example.com`, which may not necessarily match what you were asking in the title of this question.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now:

<CFLOOP array="#links#" index="link">
 <CFSET html = replace(html, link, mid(link, find(">",link)+1, len(link)-find(">",link)-4)) />
</CFLOOP>

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult and dangerous to try using regex against HTML like this (especially if it's not your HTML but is "wild" code from the Internet), for a whole host of reasons.

**The correct tool for this job is a HTML parser** that can provide a DOM for you to manipulate.

Unfortunately there aren't any for CF, so you need to look at the Java ones. I've heard good things about **[Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net)** but never used it myself.

Comment: A bad regex can potentially allow JavaScript injection (i.e. cross-site scripting).

Comment: Also, more likely (but just 'annoying' rather than 'dangerous'), is that it can cause invalid markup and thus make a page do weird things.

Comment: I can't disagree with that logic, however, the OP is asking how to match--not necessarily what he plans to do with the matched content.